# using SOAP web services with android 4.2

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask, ksoap2

I am developing an application which connects to a web services using SOAP, but I could not make the connection correctly this is my activity:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.StrictMode; 
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Autenticacion extends Activity {

//Constantes para la invocacion del web service
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String URL="http://192.168.1.66:50513/Sicam/Service1.asmx";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "MostrarProfesor";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/MostrarProfesor";

    //Declaracion de variables para consuymir el web service
    private SoapObject request=null;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=null;
    private SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP=null;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    TextView result;


    //Declaracion de variables para serealziar y deserealizar
    //objetos y cadenas JSON
    Gson gson ;
    private String  strJSON;

//Instancias a objetos tipo EditText
private EditText user, pass;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.autenticacion);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { 
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        } 
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label_user);

    // Asigna los objetos
    this.user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    this.pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
}

 public void autentificar(View view) {
     //Se crea una instancia de la clase AdminDataBase
     AdminDataBase datahelper = new AdminDataBase(this);
     //Con la instancia creada se llama al metodo open para abrir la base de datos
      SQLiteDatabase db= datahelper.open();
      //Se crean dos variables tipo String para guardar los datos de la consulta
      String adapter=null;
      String adapter1=null;
     try{
            //Se ejecuta una consulta SQLite para recueprar el nombre de usuario y contraseña
          Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("select Usuario, Contraseña from Profesor where Usuario='"+user.getText()+"' or Contraseña='"+pass.getText()+"'", null);
           startManagingCursor(fila);
        //Se verifica que existe al menos un registro
          if (fila.moveToFirst()) {           

                //Si existen registros se obtienen las columnas con datos y se asignan a las variables
                adapter =fila.getString(0);
                adapter1 =fila.getString(1);

                //Comprueba si el nombre de usuario y/o contraseña son validos
                 if(this.user.getText().toString().trim().equals(adapter)  && this.pass.getText().toString().trim().equals(adapter1)) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),                      
                          "Te has autentificado correctamente...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                     //Se inicia la actividad para pasar a la siguiente pantalla si el ingreso fue correcto
                     Intent i=new Intent(this,Menu.class);
                     i.putExtra("usuario",adapter);
                     i.putExtra("contraseña", adapter1);
                     startActivity(i);
                     this.finish();
                 }
                 else{

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),                      
                          "¡El nombre de usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }
                //Si no existe un registro en la base se manda 
                 //el siguiente mensaje para que el usuario pase a administracion a darse de alta                   
          }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Puede ser que no este registrado en la base de datos consulte al administrador", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.i("BaseDatos", "Error al recuperar datos" + e);
        }
     db.close();
     new MiTarea().execute();

 }


//Método para cancelar o salir de la aplicación
public void salida(View view){

    this.finish();
}

private class MiTarea extends AsyncTask<String, Float, String>{

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Autenticacion.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();           
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Profesor details. Please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
     }

     protected String doInBackground(String...params) {


        //Se crea un objeto SoapObject para poder realizar la peticion
        //para consumir el WS SOAP. El constructor recibe
        //el namespace. Por lo regular el namespace es el dominio
        //donde se encuentra el web service
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);




        //Se crea un objeto SoapSerializationEnvelope para serealizar la
        //peticion SOAP y permitir viajar el mensaje por la nube
        //el constructor recibe la version de SOAP
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true; //se asigna true para el caso de que el WS sea de dotNet
        //Se envuelve la peticion soap
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.dotNet = true; //se asigna true para el caso de que el WS sea de dotNet

        //Objeto que representa el modelo de transporte
        //Recibe la URL del ws
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        try {
            //Hace la llamada al ws
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            //Se crea un objeto SoapPrimitive y se obtiene la respuesta
            //de la peticion
            resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
            if(res.equals("1"))
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se pudo completar la descarga", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Log.i("1", "Se descargarón los datos");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se pudo completar la descarga" +e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.i("2", "No se descargarón los datos");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se pudo completar la descarga" +e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.i("3", "No se descargarón los datos");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Almacenamos el resultado en un String ya que lo que represa
        //el ws es una cadena json, representando una lista AndroidOS
        //de objetos del tipo
        strJSON = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
        result.setText(strJSON);


        //se crea el objeto que ayuda deserealizar la cadena JSON
          gson = new Gson();

          //Obtenemos el tipo de un ArrayList
          /*Type lstT = new TypeToken; ArrayList;(){}.getType();

          //Creamos una objeto ArrayList
          ArrayList arrListAOS = new ArrayList();

          //Deserealizamos la cadena JSON para que se convertida a un ArrayList
          arrListAOS = gson.fromJson(strJSON);

          //Asignaos la ArrayList al controls ListView para mostrar
          //la lista de SO Android que se consumieron del web service
          lsvAndroidOS.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter
          (getApplication(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrListAOS));*/


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),                     
            //  "Datos Bajados Correctamente:" + strJSON, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Log.i("4", "Se descargarón los datos");
        Log.d("Se descargarón los datos", strJSON);


         return null;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate (Float... valores) {


     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String bytes) {
         super.onPostExecute(bytes);
         if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
             this.dialog.dismiss();
                                          }             

     }
  } 
}
```

Log:

```
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133): Activity com.android.sicam.Autenticacion has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d35f38 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,144} that was originally added here
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.sicam.Autenticacion has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d35f38 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,144} that was originally added here
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.android.sicam.Autenticacion$MiTarea.onPreExecute(Autenticacion.java:138)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.android.sicam.Autenticacion.autentificar(Autenticacion.java:119)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-05 16:24:58.538: E/WindowManager(1133):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 16:24:58.997: W/System.err(1133): java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 400
04-05 16:24:59.009: W/System.err(1133):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
04-05 16:24:59.017: W/System.err(1133):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
04-05 16:24:59.017: W/System.err(1133):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
04-05 16:24:59.017: W/System.err(1133):     at com.android.sicam.Autenticacion$MiTarea.doInBackground(Autenticacion.java:170)
04-05 16:24:59.028: W/System.err(1133):     at com.android.sicam.Autenticacion$MiTarea.doInBackground(Autenticacion.java:1)
04-05 16:24:59.028: W/System.err(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-05 16:24:59.038: W/System.err(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-05 16:24:59.038: W/System.err(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-05 16:24:59.047: W/System.err(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-05 16:24:59.047: W/System.err(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-05 16:24:59.057: W/System.err(1133):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-05 16:24:59.057: W/dalvikvm(1133): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at com.android.sicam.Autenticacion$MiTarea.doInBackground(Autenticacion.java:194)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at com.android.sicam.Autenticacion$MiTarea.doInBackground(Autenticacion.java:1)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-05 16:24:59.157: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     ... 4 more
```

I declared in the manifest internet permission

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you declared window manager permission in mainfaist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, the problem was finally published my web service, why not connect and send me null pointer. I completed the subject, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason seems like a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

In your log:

`W/System.err(1057): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 4000) after 20000ms` line told us.

Instead of this code:

```
HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

try this code:

```
HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
```

[HttpTransportSE.java](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-j2se/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransportSE.java) have multiple Constructor.

```
/**
* Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
*
* @param url
* the destination to POST SOAP data
* @param timeout
* timeout for connection and Read Timeouts (milliseconds)
*/
    public HttpTransportSE(String url, int timeout) {
        super(url, timeout);
    }
```

Comment: after changing the line of my code, my change log, but still can make the request.
I edited the log

Comment: In the localhost, the IP address that I tested was the ip of my machine 192.168.1.66, and the emulator 10.0.2.2, port working in my server with iis express 50513, which would be the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite general while debugging in localhost which causes the `SocketTimeoutException`. Try a real online server and you should be fine

Comment: I tested with a real server, in the example to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit (http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx), but in this instance not got the connection. Could be a problem with the emulator or my web service?